# Calling a php script, accessing its output and using it in a function

Tags: javascript, json, post

I am accessing a 3rd party API which returns JSON data that contains image urls using a function `getResults()`. Within that function, I call another function `uploadResults()` to call a PHP script to post those image urls and receive new (branded) urls back. Then I want to save those new urls in a variable called `newURL`. Finally, I want to display this `newURL` along with the other JSON data I collected from the 3rd party API.

My JavaScript code:

```
function getResults(url){
    $.get("https:// MY API URL=" + url, function(data) {
        console.log("API call worked")
        console.log(data);

        data['result'].forEach(function(result,index,results) {
            var file = result.value_map.im_url;
            uploadResults(file);

            var itemName = result.value_map.title;
            var clickURL = result.value_map.web_url;    
            var image = "<img src=\"" + newURL + "\"/>";
            var clickableImage = "<a href=\"" + clickURL + "\">" + image + "</a>";
            var wholeImage = "<div>" + clickableImage + "<br><br>" + itemName + "<br><br><br><br></div>";
            $(".display").append(wholeImage);
        });
    });
}

function uploadResults(file){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://MY HOST/upload.php?' + file,
        cache: false,
        success: function(files){
            console.log("PHP call worked");
            console.log(files);
            var newUrl = files;
        }
    });
}
```

When I run my code in the browser I get this output in the console:

```
API call worked
Object {status: "OK", method: "uploadsearch", error: Array[0], page: 1, limit: 50…}
Uncaught ReferenceError: newURL is not defined(anonymous function) 
PHP call worked
Object {files: Array[0]}
```

Am I not calling the PHP script correctly? Am I not passing the right parameters?

Comment: So what's the `file` argument for, it's not being sent to the server ?

Comment: `url: 'http://MY HOST/upload.php?' + file,`

Comment: @adeneo, the file (url) is being uploaded to a directory and is being modified by a php script and returned as a new url.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You're not uploading it, it's not being used at all, see my comment above on how to concatenate a variable and a string

Comment: @adeneo.  Thanks.  I tried that as well.  In fact I will change it in my code now.  But I still get the same response.  Object {files: Array[0]}
files: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object